# creating a file inside a directory with os module doesn't work

Tags: python, operating-system

so im trying to create a file inside my directory from running this code

```
cur_directory = os.getcwd()
file1 = 'first.txt'
combined = os.path.join(cur_directory, file1)
print(combined)
print(os.path.exists(combined))
```

well when i run it i get this on my terminal
C:\Users.....\OsModule\first.txt
False

but in the real time when i open the Osmodule directory the first.txt seems to be non existant
and that's why it returns False

i added this to see if there was any kind of hidden problems but it looks like it the file is non existant as it returns 'False'

```
print(os.path.exists(combined))
```

Comment: Checking for a file's existence will not create it. What do you want to happen if the file already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually not writing the file.

```
with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'w') as fp:
    pass
```

Comment: i actually got the code from this tutorial and i rly want to know why and how it works in the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQppXRN841w
in 11:25

Comment: A better open mode would be 'a' or 'a+' which would [try to] create the file if it didn't exist. If it already exists then opening (and immediately closing) in either of these modes would be benign. Opening with 'w' will [try to] create a file if it does not exist or will truncate an existing file (which may not be desirable)

Answer (score 0):

Use Open() to Create a file.

```
with open('first.txt', 'w') as f:
print('first.txt created')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).